# Formatting issues for dataframe when taking values from Python to Excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Spyder to merge and concat dataframes and save them as CSV and Excel files.

The problem is that Excel saves certain characters as both dates and strange numerical values. The columns that are the issue are `ID` which are `non-null objects`.

For example I have a dataframe that has some values like this:

```
Name     ID       State
Hikki    1-01     AK
Donald   4 A      AZ
```

I'm able to view the proper values in Spyder but when I save to Excel and open it in Excel this is what some of these values look like:

```
Name     ID             State
Hikki    01-Jan         AK
Donald   0.166666667    AZ
```

This only seems to happen with very specific types - like characters with dashes or numbers with with letters.

Is there any way I can save to a direct format so that I don't have to change things manually in Excel?

Currently the only fix I have is turning some of them to `Text` format in Excel - but this only seems to work for the number to date problem and not the 4 A to random number issue.

Comment: Can you show the datatype of ID before you export it to CSV?

Comment: `ID  274764 non-null object`

Comment: .csv or .xlsx ?

Comment: Can you post the full code? I have no idea how you are actually doing the exporting.

Comment: Have you tried to put `'` at beginning of ID values?

Comment: Does the same result happen if you concatenate the 4 and A  as 4A?

Comment: This behavior by Excel is unwanted in your case, but normal.
"1-01" is interpreted as a date.
"4 A" is interpreted as 4:00 AM, wich is 1/6 of a day. Therefor 0.166666666666.
Can't you force excel to read the whole thing as a string?